# Greater than(>) and less than(<) operator not working in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, ibm-datapower

Below is my XSL where I am trying to check the condition if size of the file is greater then the preset value and try to stop the processing, but it looks like the condition is not getting executed. I am not sure if it is not formatted right way. Can anyone look in to it and see if there is any issue?

Value of both the variable IncomingFileSize and SetFileSize are of type 'number'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:dpconfig="http://www.datapower.com/param/config" extension-element-prefixes="dp" exclude-result-prefixes="dp dpconfig inc">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="File_CD" select="document('local:///FileIntake/Resources/FileServiceConfigData.xml')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="IncomingFileSize" select="number(dp:variable('var://service/mpgw/request-size'))"/>
    <!-- <xsl:variable name="SetFileSize" select="$File_CD/FileServiceConfig/FileSize"/> -->
    <xsl:variable name="SetFileSize" select="number($File_CD/FileServiceConfig/FileSize)"/>
    <dp:set-variable name="'var://context/var/IncomingFileSize'" value="$IncomingFileSize"/>
    <dp:set-variable name="'var://context/var/SetFileSize'" value="$SetFileSize"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="'$IncomingFileSize '&gt;' $SetFileSize'">
            <dp:reject/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <dp:accept/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Why do you have single quotes around `$IncomingFileSize` and `$SetFileSize` in the `xsl:when/@test`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out where I went wrong. Below is the correct way to write the condition. I had put unnecessary single quotes.

```
<xsl:when test="$IncomingFileSize &gt; $SetFileSize">
```

Comment: Or `<xsl:when test="$IncomingFileSize > $SetFileSize">`. Only the opening bracket `<` needs to be escaped as `&lt;`.